# 9-patch not working

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm having strange issues with 9-patch png's on Android.
It already fails in Eclipse visual editor, no matter which target I use (tried several between 7 and 14).
The error log shows the message *main.xml: Index: 0, Size: 0*
The exception behind is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:185)
at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:101)
at android.graphics.NinePatch_Delegate$1.draw(NinePatch_Delegate.java:219)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.drawInLayer(GcSnapshot.java:613)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.draw(GcSnapshot.java:583)
at android.graphics.NinePatch_Delegate.draw(NinePatch_Delegate.java:217)
at android.graphics.NinePatch_Delegate.nativeDraw(NinePatch_Delegate.java:170)
at android.graphics.NinePatch.nativeDraw(NinePatch.java)
at android.graphics.NinePatch.draw(NinePatch.java:120)
at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.draw(NinePatchDrawable.java:189)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10865)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2899)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2897)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2897)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2899)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2897)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10883)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2899)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10883)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:505)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:324)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1323)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1077)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:903)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.pageChange(LayoutEditor.java:399)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:290)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1282)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1267)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:2746)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1433)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:257)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3588)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3209)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

The 9-patch was created with the draw9patch-tool included in the SDK.
I have this issues with all the images I use in this project. I already used 9-patch before in other projects without problems and thus assume there's something specific to the format of my current png's. Maybe the used Photoshop of the designer creates png's which result in invalid 9-patches.
Does anybody have an idea what's the issue here?

**update:**

working version:

[image]

not working version:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the actual 9-patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in SDK 16 / 17, see here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39814

and here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37472

Comment: didn't try it, but looks like that's it

Answer (score 10):

You just missed set content area.

Draw borders at RIGHT & BOTTOM of your 9 patch png.[image]

Comment: According to the android documentation, what you're calling content area is optional padding box: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: Yes this work for me, thanks.Although it is optional but without this does work and with this it works. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you have added 9Patch image in only one of the folders like only in `drawable-xhdpi` then it will reproduce such error, you should put it either in just `drawable` folder or all the folders like `drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi, etc`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem here was:
the not working version misses a 2 px transparent border. Still strange however that draw9patch didn't complain about that and showed is at working.